# How can I control my phone remotely?

Tags: security, remote-control, remote-access

As a new Android user, this question has had me thinking quite a while. Is it possible to create an app or is there an app available that will do the following;

- Remote access to your device
- Impossible to remove from your phone (rooting, flashing, w/e)
- Turn your phone into 'Lost Mode' and make sure it can only be used remotely and disables all but the useful services to find your phone (camera, gps, etc)

OR

- Impossible to remove from your phone (even after reinstall, etc)
- Remains in the background whilst the person is using your phone as theirs (stolen, swiped and reinstalled)

Comment: It's important to note that a factory reset will eliminate pretty much any method of protecting or wiping your phone remotely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google's [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) service can do all of that apart from the remote control, though unless your phone has a new enough OS to have it installed by default (instead of pulled down as part of the Google Services updates) it's difficult to remove rather than impossible.

- [Find your lost phone with Android Device manager](http://officialandroid.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/find-your-lost-phone-with-android.html)
- [Remotely lock Android devices](http://googlesystem.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/remotely-lock-android-devices.html)

Answer (score 1):

Making an app "impossible to remove" is, of course, impossible to accomplish. Nothing is impossible to remove.

For other features you're looking for, I'd recommend looking into [AirDroid](http://www.appbrain.com/app/airdroid/com.sand.airdroid) or [Cerberus](http://www.appbrain.com/app/cerberus-anti-theft/com.lsdroid.cerberus).